# pandas extract right hand values, find starting point using end position of substring

Tags: python, pandas, find, substring

I've done the following in excel. Can't replicate in pandas. Have the following dataset:

```
 0      PRJ - 01999777
 1      PRJ-0198953
 2      PRJ- 01879966
 3      PRJ - 21879966
 4      PRJ - 91879966
 ... 
646        0501164732
```

I want to extract the numbers to the right into a new column to get the following:

```
01999777
0198953
01879966
21879966
91879966
... 
0501164732
```

I used the following to get the position of the '- ' using:

```
dfSP['temp'] = map(lambda x: x.find('- '), dfSP[appnocol])
```

appnocol is the variable name that holds the column name for the original data. 'temp' is the new column I want to write the count into. I then extract the value into a new column 'appnonew' within a where as this is only applicable for certain rows

```
dfSP['appnonew'] = np.where((dfSP[pacol] == lpa[1]), df['appnocol'].apply(lambda x: x[dfSP[appnocol]:100]), '')
```

I get an error

*'string indices must be integers'*

This is because the first line does not return an integer in 'temp' but: ''

Any suggestions to fix or is there a different way to do this? Thanks

Comment: `dfSP['col'].str.split("-").str[1]`? or `rsplit("-").str[1]`?

Comment: that worked I was able to put into the where statement:

dfSP['appnonew'] = np.where((dfSP[pacol] == lpa[1]), dfSP[appnocol].str.split("- ").str[1], '')